# How to continuously move object in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, button, imageview

How to continuously move an ImageView in Android Studio when a Button is held down, but stop when it isnt clicked anymore? With other words: how to detect if a button is "unclicked§ or direktly detect if it is held down. Thanks for the help

Comment: [touchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

To detect if a button is pressed/released(down/up), TouchListener is used.

```
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    root_layout = findViewById(R.id.root_layout); //parent layout

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            float x = imageView.getX();
            if(x > root_layout.getWidth())
                x = 0;
            else
                x += 6; //Increase value of '6' to move the imageView faster
            imageView.setX(x);

            handler.postDelayed(this,0); //increase delay '0' if facing lag. 
            // This is the rate at which the x value of our imageView is being updated
            
        }
    };

    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    handler.post(runnable); //Start moving imageView
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable); //Stop moving imageView
                    break;
            }
        return true;
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: when i create a handler, it says i need to implement some methods. What do i do?

Comment: you are importing 'java.util.logging.Handler'. Instead import 'android.os.Handler'

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

> Step 1:- need to define anim folder in your res folder.

now place rotate.xml file in anim folder.

`rotate.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="600"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"/>

</set>
```

> Step 2:- Declare animation programmatically

```
// Animation
    Animation animFadein;

in onCreate()
// load the animation
        animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.rotate);
```

> Step 3:- Detect user touch like this to start and stop animation

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //start animation here
           imageView.startAnimation(animFadein);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // stop animation here
             imageView.stopAnimation(animFadein);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```